# How to migrate .dtsx package which executes python script to SSIS Linux using dtexec?

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, ssis, dtexec

I am migrating SSIS ETL from Windows to Linux and using dtexec.
In Windows, the executables can be added as ...python.exe. I would like to know how the same can be migrated to Linux as python3 will be present in `/usr/bin/python3`.

I have tried adding paths like `C:\usr\bin\python3` as SSIS on Linux maps the Windows-style path `C:\test` to the Linux-style path `/test`. But it didn't work.

The error is caused by this command:

```
/opt/ssis/bin/dtexec /Pack xxx.dtsx /Proj xxx.ispac /decrypt test
```

> Error: 2022-01-13 20:10:42.83
> Code: 0xC002F304
> Source: DDL Execute Process Task
> Description: An error occurred with the following error message: "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.".

Comment: I would create a new package which has as Execute Process Task and figure out what it takes to make that run any command in a Linux environment. Something as trivial as `ls` or `df` just ensure that you _can_ invoke a command from an SSIS package. I am out of the game when it comes to SSIS on Linux but I'd be surprised if MS invested Engineering dollars on that.